# Black screen with only cursor AFTER LOGIN on braswell and cherrytrail with Linux 5.7 (i915)

Tags: linux-kernel, intel-graphics, opengl, i915

I've built the current 5.7.14 kernel and am running into an issue on my Brasswel (N3150) and CherryTrail (Atom x5-Z8350) systems. The former runs an old Ubuntu 14.04.6LTS system, the latter runs Devuan Beowulf (off an external drive).

The greeter (SDDM) seems to work fine but gives me a black screen with just the mouse cursor when I 1) login or 2) click the session selector.

I have a hunch this has to do with the compositor or OpenGL more in general: hitting Shift-Alt-F12 in KDE Plasma to disable KWin's compositor gives me back at least a part of the image.

Both systems work fine with the 4.19.118 kernel; the Devuan install also works fine with 5.7.14 on an HP laptop with an i3 CPU that's a few years old now.

I haven't found anything relevant; testing with i915 powersaving, fastboot and experimental hw support didn't help me solve the problem. Any idea what I can try short of building a 5.6 kernel in hope it'll work properly?

(installing Devuan's own kernels will force me to install apparmor which I'd prefer to avoid.)

Comment: I can now confirm that this also happens with the 5.7.14 Liquorix kernel as well as Devuan's own 5.7 kernel package.

Comment: FWIW, the 5.6.19 kernel works fine on both systems, but on the N3150 I need to tweak the i915 driver parameters as a function of the userland. Booting Devuan Beowulf I can used the preferred `enable_fbc=1 fastboot=1 enable_psr=1` combo, but booting my updated 14.04 Frankubuntu I need to set `enable_psr=0` to avoid a disabling screen flicker.